# Nginx Phusion Passenger: "passenger_log_file" directive is not allowed

Tags: node.js, nginx, passenger

I'm currently running: nginx/1.12.2 with Phusion Passenger 5.1.12.

Whenever I try to use "passenger_log_file", "passenger_default_user" or "passenger_default_group" I get the following error.

nginx: [emerg] "passenger_log_file" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test:11

My sites-enabled file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /home/test/api;

    passenger_app_root /home/test/api/dist;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_type node;
    passenger_startup_file app.js;
    passenger_log_file /var/log/test/access.log;
}
```

If I remove the passenger_log_file everything works perfectly fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: Make sure that log dir has correctly set up permissions to nginx.

Comment: @julian-salas the log dir is owned by the correct user. Even tried changing the directory to 777 and the log file to 666, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I think the correct option for your case is **passenger_app_log_file** which allow to define a log file for each app. Unfortunately this is an [Enterprise](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_app_log_file) level option. In other hand if you move your **passenger_log_file** a level up it should change all your passenger apps log file from the default one.

```
    passenger_log_file /var/www/vhosts/system/xxx.pasi-consulting.com/logs/proxy_error_log;

    server {
    listen 137.74.195.27:443 ssl http2;

    server_name www.pasi-consulting.com;
    server_name www.xxx.pasi-consulting.com;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Per the [documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_log_file)

`passenger_log_file` is only available at the `http` context level. In your provided example it is in the `server` context.

Both `passenger_default_user` and `passenger_default_group` are allowed in the `server` context so that is confusing.